# UICollectionView - vertical scrollling, horizontal paging with custom layout

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm trying to implement an iOS collection view which basically should work similar to a table view, but the cells' widths being integer multiples of the collection view's width (eg. 4 times the width). the collection view should scroll vertically (like a regular tableview does), but it should page horizontally across the content.

I do have the custom layout working except for the paging. Currently, the collectionView will just scroll horizontally. I'm unsure how to implement the paging correctly.

If I just set `pagingEnabled` on the collectionView, it has no effect. I suspect that the scrollview needs to be told what the width of a page is..?

Or do I have to do anything weird because there is only one cell/column per row, instead of multiple cells?

See the image; the grey bars are the cells, the blue rect is the collection view frame.

thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe if the collection view item widths are less than or equal to the width of the collection view, then the horizontal paging should work via the `pagingEnabled` property. Otherwise, you need to create the paging effect yourself using the `UIScrollView` delegate methods and animating to offsets yourself after a certain threshold